# Regexp to find words with apostrophe

Tags: regex

I have string, something like that:

```
You're so beaulifull! Don't say me no!
```

if i try to match all words by regexp, using `\w+` i'll get output like that:

```
    You
    re
    so
    beaulifull
    Don
    t
    say
    me
    no
```

but what regex should i use to match words with apostrophe, so output will be correct?

Comment: [\w']+   will do it

Comment: And if it will be this `[a-zA-Z_]`

Comment: What outputs are you expecting from the above string? Should the output be two words with You're and Don't ?

Comment: Do you want words containing only, letters, underscores, and apostrophes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a character class including both `\w` and an apostrophe literal, so something like this: `[\w']+`

Comment: and if it will be this `[a-zA-Z_]`?

Comment: @Proxima I'm assuming you're asking how to use that regex, so try this `[a-zA-Z_']+`. The point is that you need to include the apostrophe in the character class so it's part of the match.

Answer (score 1):

Regex: `/\w+\'\w+/g`

To verify this quick, we can go to the browser console and check the following:

```
var str = "You're so beaulifull! Don't say me no!";
str.match(/\w+\'\w+/g);
```

gives us: `["You're", "Don't"]`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a word starting or ending with an apostrophe `[\w']+` will suffice.

However; if you don't want neither of those you could try something like this: `\w+('\w+)?`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
\w+(?:'\w+)*
\b\p{L}+(?:'\p{L}+)*\b
```

See [regex #1](https://regex101.com/r/MDAkzB/1) and [regex #2 demo](https://regex101.com/r/MDAkzB/2).

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `\p{L}+` - one or more letters
- `(?:'\p{L}+)*` - zero or more sequences of a `'` char followed with one or more letters
- `\b` - a word boundary